# Is there any alternative for System.Web.Security MemberShipUser in DotNetCore

Tags: c#, .net-core

I want to use MembershipUser class for this,but in core I am not able to do so. What is the alternative for this

```
 public static void SendResetEmail(MembershipUser user, ControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
      //some code
    }
```

Comment: Where is your `MembershipUser` comes from at the moment?

Comment: Its not coming from anywhere. I am migrating asp.net project to .net core. So In old project it was coming by using System.Web.Security. Now In .netCore there is nothing like that

Comment: I can't come from anywhere, it must live in some assembly. If you mention `System.Web.Secuirty`, then it is probably [this class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.membershipuser?view=netframework-4.7.2). In this case you are out of luck. Core has a new version of security framework Identity 3. Maybe [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47861712/net-identity-3-on-existing-solution) can help to get you going

Comment: For any future searchers this migration article from Microsoft might be of assistance [Migrate from ASP.NET Membership authentication to ASP.NET Core 2.0 Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/proper-to-2x/membership-to-core-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1)